# Package's trajectory, impact and displacement

Tags: calculus

[image: Sketch]

(Star represents the plane, dots- trajectory, box- the package, "~"-vector)

The white UN-plane is
flying horizontally at 450 km/
h as it drops its first food package from
an altitude of 2000 m. Assume the acceleration due to gravity ||~*g*|| = 9.81 m/
s2 and ignore
air friction and wind. (Only *exact expressions* in S.I.-units may score.)

1. Draw this situation including the estimated trajectory of this package (a simplied
   sketch suffices).

I would like to know if the drawing is correct ( I wanted to show that the package is moving directly below the plane until landing).

2. Calculate the according (horizontal) displacement of this package. A constant expression in meter suffices.

I calculated the time it takes to reach the ground t=20,2s. 450km/h=125m/s. Are there any formulas which could help me to find the horizontal displacemet?

Answer (score 0):

Without air resistance, the horizontal velocity is constant.  As you say, it is the speed of the plane.  Just multiply by the time to reach the ground for displacement.

For 1, you are expected to show the path of the package as a parabola.  I would be worried by the statement that only exact expressions may score because your time is a rounded number.  It is correctly rounded to one place, so you are deriving it correctly.

Comment: So what you're saying is that I should use t=20s? Or calculate the displacement with t=20.2s and then round it? (There was a second question which required to calculate the time so I think the answer to it should also be an exact expression. Then for displacement it should also be t=20s.)

Comment: $20.2$ is not accurate enough to get the displacement to the nearest meter.  At $125 m/sec$ you move a meter in $0.008$ seconds, so you need a time more accurate than that.  The value of $g$ is only three places, so unless you consider it exact you don't have accurate enough data to get the answer to the nearest meter.  I find the "exact expressions" phrase troubling.  If we are to consider the accuracy of the numbers, the altitude only has $1$ significant place.